# Powershell Variable Scopes

Tags: powershell, variables, scope, global-variables

I have trouble understanding the difference between the `script:` scope and the `global:` scope, **when using them** ***in a script***.

Can someone give me an example, in which a global-scoped variable **retains** it's value and the scipt-scoped variable **does not**?

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx):

> Global:
>   The scope that is in effect when Windows PowerShell starts. Variables and functions that are present when Windows PowerShell starts have been created in the global scope. This includes automatic variables and preference variables. This also includes the variables, aliases, and functions that are in your Windows PowerShell profiles.
>   [...]
>   Script:
>   The scope that is created while a script file runs. Only the commands in the script run in the script scope. To the commands in a script, the script scope is the local scope.

Example:

```
PS C:\> $foo = 'a'
PS C:\> Get-Content .\test.ps1
"global 1: $global:foo"
"script 1: $script:foo"
$foo = 'b'                 # <- this modifies $foo in the script scope
"global 2: $global:foo"
"script 2: $script:foo"
$global:foo = 'c'          # <- this modifies $foo in the global scope
"global 3: $global:foo"
"script 3: $script:foo"
PS C:\> .\test.ps1
global 1: a
script 1:
global 2: a
script 2: b
global 3: c
script 3: b
PS C:\> $foo
c
```

Comment: Of course I read that. Still dont getting it.
And the question was: is there a difference when using them both in a script. You did not do that in your example.

Comment: Umm... yes, I did.

Comment: Really? You did assign 'a' outside the script.

Comment: And also you did not use either $script:abc = "a" or $global:xyz = "b" in that script.
I want to understand, if it makes a difference, if  I assign(!) a variable inside(!) a script, to the script:-scope or the global:-scope.

Comment: Do you think you can manage to test simple things like that yourself? I'm willing to explain stuff, but I most definitely won't spoon-feed you the documentation.

Comment: Look nobody forces you to answer, but if you do stop being so condescending. You act like I rang you up in the middle of the night. Chill, man.
I have read the help, I tested it in all ways i can think of inside a script (and in a script calling a script), I cant see a difference.  
But I am not sure, because sometimes you have to know what to look for, to find it.